# How do I update a table that references duplicate records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, sql-update, inner-join

I have two SQL tables. One gets a reference value from another table which stores a list of Modules and their ID. But these descriptions are not unique. I am trying to remove the duplicates of Table A but I'm not sure how to update Table B to only reference the single values.

Example:

```
Table A:                                      Table B:

--------------------------------            ------------------------------------
ID      Description      RefID               ID            Name       
--------------------------------            ------------------------------------
1       Test 1           2                   1            QuickReports
--------------------------------            ------------------------------------
2       Test 2           1                   2            QuickReports
--------------------------------            ------------------------------------
```

I want the results to be the following:

```
Table A:                                      Table B:

--------------------------------            ------------------------------------
ID      Description      RefID               ID            Name       
--------------------------------            ------------------------------------
1       Test 1           1                   1            QuickReports
--------------------------------            ------------------------------------
2       Test 2           1                  
--------------------------------
```

I managed to delete duplicates from table B using the below code but I haven't been able to update the records in Table A. Each table have over 500 records each.

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT 
        Name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY
            Name
        ORDER BY 
            Name
        )row_num
    FROM ReportmodulesTest
)
    DELETE FROM cte
    WHERE row_num > 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that has made this process easier. I first use `Row_Number` to find duplicates in Table A and `SELECT INTO` a temporary table.

```
SELECT
       a.Id
     , a.Name
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Id DESC) RN
INTO
     #TestTable
FROM
     TableA a WITH(NOLOCK)
```

I then `JOIN` Table A and Table B to see where the ID's match and identify which ID I need to keep and which ID's I need to delete:

```
SELECT
       b.Id
     , b.Name
     , b.RefId
     , ToKeep.Id   KeepId
     , ToDelete.Id DeleteId
FROM
     #TestTable ToDelete
     JOIN TableB b WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON b.RefId = ToDelete.Id
     JOIN #TestTable ToKeep
        ON ToDelete.Name = ToKeep.Name
           AND ToKeep.RN = 1
WHERE ToDelete.RN > 1
```

Then using a similar statement, I just update the records:

```
UPDATE b
SET
    b.RefId = ToKeep.Id,
FROM #TestTable ToDelete
     JOIN TableB b WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON b.RefId = ToDelete.Id
     JOIN #TestTable ToKeep
        ON ToDelete.Name = ToKeep.Name
           AND ToKeep.RN = 1
WHERE
      ToDelete.RN > 1
```

Lastly, I can now delete the duplicate records:

```
DELETE a
FROM #TestTable b
     INNER JOIN TableA a
        ON b.Id = a.Id
WHERE
      b.RN > 1
```

After this, you can use the same first `SELECT` statement to ensure that all duplicates are deleted. Just remove the `SELECT INTO` statement.

Thanks to an anonymous colleague of mine for this solution and hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to update table A first, before deleting from table B.

You tagged your question MySQL but that database would not support the `delete` statement that you are showing. I suspect that you are running SQL Server, so here is how to do it in *that* database:

```
update a
set refid = b.minid
from tablea
inner join (select name, id, min(id) over(partition by name) minid from tableb) b 
    on b.id = a.id and b.minid <> a.id
```

In MySQL, you would phrase the same query as:

```
update tablea a
from tablea
inner join (select name, id, min(id) over(partition by name) minid from tableb) b on b.id = a.id
set a.refid = b.minid
where b.minid <> a.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update the first table using :

```
update a join
       (select b.*,
               min(id) over (partition by name) as min_id
        from b
       ) b
       on a.refid = b.id
    set a.refid = b.min_id
    where a.refid <> b.min_id;
```

Then, you can delete rows in the second table with a similar logic :

```
delete b
    from b join
         (select b.*,
                 min(id) over (partition by name) as min_id
          from b
         ) bb
         on bb.id = b.id
    where b.id <> bb.min_id;
```