# Update table that references duplicates Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, duplicates, sql-delete

I have two tables `Table A` and `Table B`. I need `Table A` to reference `Table B` but I first need to delete the duplicates of `Table B` and have `Table A` reference the new `ID`.

At the moment I am able to partition the records using `WITH TIES` but how do I ensure that each record points to the correct reference?

Example:

```
Table A
```

| Name | RefId |
| --- | --- |
| Item 1 | 251 |
| Item 2 | 251 |
| Item 3 | 167 |
| Item 4 | 75 |

```
Table B
```

| Name | RefId |
| --- | --- |
| Report1 | 251 |
| Report2 | 251 |
| Report1 | 167 |
| Report1 | 75 |

Expected output:

```
Table C
```

| Name | RefId |
| --- | --- |
| Item 1 | 6 |
| Item 2 | 6 |
| Item 3 | 5 |
| Item 4 | 6 |

The code I am using to basically partition the records and remove duplicates is:

```
 SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES Name
    FROM ReportTable
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name DESC)
```

But this doesn't actually update any records that reference this table. I also have the following code to delete duplicates but again, I'm not sure how I would go about updating the records that reference this table.

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT nmt.Name, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY nmt.Name ORDER BY nmt.Name) row_num
         FROM dbo.ReportTable nmt)
     DELETE FROM cte
     WHERE row_num > 1;
```

Comment: Whence is the source of the `RefId` in the expected output?

Comment: When I use the query (With Ties) it basically filters out duplicates and assigns a new `refId` to the results

Comment: You can find the answer here : [Delete Duplicates and Update References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65340539/how-do-i-update-a-table-that-references-duplicate-records/65625592#65625592)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UPDATE` in `tableA` first then `delete` duplicate from `TableB` as follows:

```
update tableA A
set A.ref_id = 
     (select max(ref_id) 
        from tableB 
       where name in (select name 
                        from tableB B 
                       where B.ref_id = A.ref_id))

delete from tableB B
 where exists 
       (select 1 from tableB BB
         where BB.NAME = B.NAME
           AND BB.ref_id > B.ref_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! The `UPDATE` query you have though updates all records to the Max ID and not to the respective MAX ID